# How to give irreducible factorization in $\mathbb{Z}_5$?

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, factoring

I have this polynomial:

$$f=x^5+2x^3+4x^2+x+4$$

How can i find the irreducible factorization(in $\mathbb{Z}_5$)?I can find the roots easily but thats not enough.

Comment: If you don't know by heart some of the irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ over $\mathbb Z_5$, you can just brute force it. Write $f(x)=(x^2+a_1x+a_0)(x^3+b_2x^2+b_1x+b_0)$, foil the RHS, equate coefficients, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\pm2$ are zeroes of the polynomial, $f$ has linear factors $x-2$ and $x+2$. We have $f(x) = (x-2)(x+2)(x^3+x-1)$. The quotient $x^3+x-1$ is cubic and has no linear factor over $\mathbb{F}_5$, hence is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$.